# What's the best Django app/forum that is super simple and can use the existing Django authentication system?

Tags: python, django, templates, forum

I want to wrap it inside a template. That's very important.

Comment: I want to understand the question.  That's very important, too.  As it is, the question makes almost no sense at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795539/what-are-the-best-django-forum-app-options-out-there

Comment: I think what TIMEX is looking for is a simple forum solution (like vanillaforums.org) that can readily be used within a Django app. Along with support for the contrib.auth system, lest you force users to create 2 accounts for your 1 site.

Comment: I would be very interested to hear of any potential gems out there, as I'm looking for the exactly the same thing!

Answer (score 3):

There a several forum app exists for django.
Look here  [django forums](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/forums/)
And specially look at [DjangoBB](http://www.djangobb.org/)